# Python string treated differently when extracted from list

Tags: python

I'm extracting values from a list to pass through to the Twitter API and getting an "Authentication Failed" message. Authentication works when if I explicitly assign the same exact strings to variables and use them.

This works (variables):

```
consumer_key = "MyConsumerKey"
consumer_secret = "MyConsumerSecret"
access_token = "MyAccessToken"
access_token_secret = "MyAccessTokenSecret"
    
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_profile(name= "my name")
```

This fails (from list):

```
tokens = [["MyConsumerKey", "MyConsumerSecret", "MyAccessToken", "MyAccessTokenSecret"]]
consumer_key = tokens[0][0]
consumer_secret = tokens[0][1]
access_token = tokens[0][2]
access_token_secret = tokens[0][3]
    
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_profile(name= "my name")
```

How do I get Python to treat the strings extracted from lists the same as those assigned to variables?

Comment: I don't think the list looks like that in the code you're apparently having trouble with. It's a strange structure but nothing inherently wrong

Comment: I had the same issue using Pandas df, and numpy array. The list was just the way I chose to illustrate the code here.

Comment: Did you try printing the values of the strings in the case that fails? There is no difference between using list or strings directly...

Comment: The code you posted will assign exactly the same values in both cases, so the issue must be somewhere else. Try printing the variables before passing them to the API

Comment: Yes, printing the two versions returns the exact same result.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem as described. The string values are all equal between the first snippet and second. There must be something else happening. For example, maybe in your real code, the list is from JSON and you're not decoding it properly. Please make a [mre]. If you want more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Could you edit your post and add your error message?

Comment: This is the closest I can get to a reproducible example without posting API credentials. It is literally the example I'm working through with placeholders. Here is the error message: "Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
32 - Could not authenticate you."

Comment: Have you tried comparing the two? try `print(tokens[0][0] == 'MyConsumerKey')` and see if that prints true

Comment: @aawige Maybe there's a typo in the API creds

Comment: I solved it. It was a typo error in the strings stored in my db. Apologies and thanks for helping me work through this.